# Website content fully loaded using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, web, preload

I am thinking about making my website completely ajax loaded, to improve responsiveness, and I expect overall efficiency. There seems to be no downside to it.

- I am planning to have the website installed as an ordinary wordpress site, with many ordinary pages, but after the page loads, ajax methods are used to overload all links, and text content from other pages will be pre-loaded, whilst graphics will be lazy loaded.
- I am planning to find a library to handle the browser history (not sure how hard it will be to handle this cross platform)
- Is there an example of this kind of thing being done already? Is it common?
- is there something I am missing?

Comment: The downside is that you're really only faking the "responsiveness", why not improve the overall site performance instead and just decrease load times?

Comment: I think this is pretty common, but don't go overboard. Most networks are pretty fast nowadays, and can easily load at least some basic page skeleton which can be filled in by AJAX. AJAX should only be used for content that would take time to load.

Comment: @TomWalters could you elaborate on how I could improve responsiveness without improving load times?

Comment: @Linuxios I live in Ethiopia, and download speeds are pretty slow here. I expect to see a significant improvement in page loading times, and therefore site responsiveness. It is pretty common for people to load pages in tabs and read other things whilst the page is loading, so I hope that pre-loading the text content will allow people to stay on one page, and read the whole site uninterrupted. Having said that, maybe there is a solution by better caching the main assets... do you have any advice?

Comment: Well basically with AJAX you'd be loading in a frame in the normal way, then populating with content while displaying your own loading setup I'm guessing, and while this is certainly one approach, I think users prefer sites to just load in their full form straight away. Have a look around for improving a sites performance through caching, compression, and so on. There are powerful plugins for Wordpress to help here, check out W3 Total Cache as an example.

Comment: @BillyMoon: I see. (Sorry, I'm used to US speeds). I suggest loading basic text assets statically (part of the HTML file), then first prefetch visible text, then text that would need to be scrolled to, then graphics, and then things like ads, videos, etc. Go for content first, looks second.

Comment: I would also be mindful of the case where someone clicks one of your links *before* it's been able to be retrieved via AJAX.  This could be confusing to a user.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not write your own from scratch?  Have you already figured out wordpress code?  Also, server-side's still good for the initial load state.  But you could probably rewrite wordpress ajaxified with jquery in "no time".

Comment: @TomWalters: Yes, but see the info on slow download speeds. In places like US and UK, it's easy to forget.

Comment: You should read up on Twitter's performance issues with a more ajax centric front end... I couldn't find the article when I looked but I heard about it on a Herding Code podcast probably ... sorry, my info here is vague

Comment: But realistically you'll be downloading the same amount of content just in a different way. If you maximise use of compression and so fourth you'll improve a site's loading time. It just comes down to the experience you wish to provide.